# UIWebView contentEditable image copy paste crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uiwebview

I am loading some html content in a `UIWebView`. The content looks something like this

```
<img alt="" src="/image/968" style="width: 75px; height: 26px;">qweqwwqeqwe<img src="/image/969" width="32" height="32"></p>
```

This part works fine. I am using the `contentEditable` property of `UIWebView` supported from iOS5.0 onwards. I wrap the content inside a

```
<div contentEditable="true">mycontent</div>.
```

I am able to write/copy text etc. But when I try to select and copy an image from the `webView` and paste it at the next line, my app is crashing (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`). I am running iOS 5.1.1 on iPad 1. I have tried checking

```
 [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] image]
 [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] images]

 [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] url]
 [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] urls]
```

but they are always either `null` or contain zero object after I copy the image and check them. Any pointers would be much appreciated?

[image]

Comment: Where do you write the objects to the pasteboard? Show that code.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I don't write the objects to pasteboard, I think when I copy something using the callouts, the OS does the writing. But I am not interested in what gets written on the pasteboard. I just put that in the question because I assumed that might help with my problem. My question is: Why is my app crashing when I try to copy paste an image from a contentEditable UIWebView that has images in the html loaded inside it?

Comment: @crypticcoder have you used the same code I have written yet because my code is working here. I have tested it first and then paste here.

Comment: can you add the crash message? (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Comment: @JennEve there is an crash message addend to post..

Comment: @crypticcoder Have you tried to run it on a simulator with Instruments and Zombies Template? It looks like a "typical" overreleased memory issue like release on autoreleased object. Maybe you construct HTML string with [NSString stringWithFormat:] and release it later?

Comment: @DanielBauke I have tried it in Zombies Template. I am very familiar to the usage of instruments in zombies template. I couldn't make out anything in this particular crash. Instruments/Zombies gives no clues.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the following code to load html string into `webView` and edit it.
It is working perfectly.

```
#import "WebViewEditViewController.h"

@interface WebViewEditViewController ()

@end

@implementation WebViewEditViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
 NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

 NSString *htmlString=@"<html><body><div contentEditable=\"true\"><img alt=\"\" src=\"1.jpg\" style=\"width: 100px; height: 100px;\">qweqwwqeqwe<img src=\"2.jpg\" width=\"150px\" height=\"70px\"></p></div></body></html>";
 [_webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I have tried printing logs after copy and found that `[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] image]` is pasting `null` in both cases while code is working fine.

Comment: @Ai_boy copy and pasting the image crashes the app on iPad Simulator iOS 5.1 xcode 4.3.2.

Comment: @Hercules copy and pasting the image crashes the app on iPad Simulator iOS 5.1 xcode 4.3.2.